# USB-C Hub/Splitter for Phone

Tags: usb, smartphones, headphones, power, hub

What I'm looking for is something that will allow my to charge and access the USB-C port at the same time. Something that only does that would be ideal but a full USB hub that will also charge my phone is good too. The problem being that using USB OTG or even headphone now that manufacturers have apparently decided to do away with 3.5mm jacks can't be done while charging without something like this.

Answer (score 0):

So I it baffles me why I haven't been able to find one yet that has great reviews but I found this one online that seems like it should work.  As a working although clunky solution you should be able to use the following [USB C Hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N0R1F1M) and then plug you USB C to 3.5mm adapter into it.  It may depend on your device though ultimately.  The reviews says it works for the Pixel and HTC 10.  [This ones was reviews were so bad I don't think it is worth buying](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075V5LRBG).